# Chips for player not attending?

Tags: tournament, blinds

So we were having a set of 10 private tournaments where points and money were taking along to a grand final where chips at the final were given by the amount of points each player had won in the previous tournaments.

We had a player who couldn’t attend at the final but had quite a few points. We ended up bringing his chips to the table and paying the blinds until there were no left.

Now, I can’t figure out if this is the best decision. The players sitting next to the chips were having kind of a bonus to their pots which doesn’t seem to make sense. It wasn’t like: “he might come by” and then giving him the benefit of the doubt. He couldn’t come.

There must be some kind of pros or mathematical/statistical idea of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is standard procedure to simply chip off a tournament player away from their seat. The player qualified for the tournament and may play it anyway they want including not showing up.

I have heard stories of players passing away at the table and still making the money. If you pick up a players chips for absence it brings up the question of a refund. If you say OK we refund a player whom does not show up, this would become a tactic of not showing up when your doing bad. (although refunding before the tournament starts would be fine).

This method is not perfectly fair, it is likely it is much more simple and fair then anything else we might come up with. Imagine a scenario were the player had 90% of the chips on the table, the remaining players would be generally screwed with highly diminished chances to go much further without the chance to get some chips back from the player. What if you don't know if the player is not going to show up or is simply late. When do you pick up the chips? The edge a player gets from a player being chipped offed at their table is not much. Also for security and accounting reasons it is always a difficult thing to change the number of chips in play within a tournament.